# How to define on back event for android alert builder?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my android app, I have an alert dialog, and I want to override the back pressed event and also make the alert dismiss in the end.

But there is an issue, when I click back, the back event, occurs twice for some reason. I tried to fix that by putting a global variable "loaded" and set it to true when I do it the first time. But this doesn't seems like a good way. Does anyone know whats wrong here?

I implemented it like this:

```
        String[] items = new String[names.size()];
        items = names.toArray(items);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("");

        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                File pickedFile = files.get(which);
                try {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(pickedFile);
                    String gradesheetData = "";
                    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                        gradesheetData += scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
                    }
                    scanner.close();

                    gs = GsonParser.getGson().fromJson(gradesheetData, GradeSheet.class);
                    ShowData();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                ShowData();
            }
        });

        builder.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    if (!loaded) {
                        loaded = true;
                        ShowData();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        builder.create();
        builder.show();
```

Comment: Can you please post the fullcode..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding `onKeyDown()` method, you can use override the `onDismiss()` method of the `Dialog` to achieve what you want. But if you must use the above code itself, might I suggest you to add this statement `return true;` in your `onKeyDown()` method's `if` block. That might get your job done too

Answer (score 0):

You need to return true here.. It is causing problem...

```
builder.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                ShowData();

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I fixed it, i just used setOnCancelListener.